# How can I add custom domain in portal azure?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, sitecore8

I try like this :

[image]

I have input my custom domain and click validate. It appears like a picture. I was confused what should I do next. There is no verify button

If I check on docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain, there exist verify button

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The easiest way is to create a CNAME record with your domain name registar pointing to the Azure website (sitecore-xxxxx-sm.azurewebsites.net)

Comment: @Kane How do I create a CNAME record with my domain name? I did not find the create button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue will occur if you haven't added a CNAME record pointing to your website(sitecore-xxxxx-sm.azurewebsites.net).

If you bought the domain from azure, you can follow the steps below.

[image]

1.Click the domain name under **App Service Domains** part. You will be redirected to the management page.

2.Click '**Manage DNS records**'

[image]

3.click 'Record set' to add a CNAME record.

[image]

If you bought the domain from other platform, you need to go to their domain management page to configure this, the steps are similar.

Comment: SoI have to buy a domain?  Actually this is staging server. I need to add www in my staging server for testing. I want to test when a user accesses a domain without www, it will redirect to www. But no problem. I will try it in my production server

Comment: @SuccessMan Yes, before you can add a custom domain name, create your domain name with a domain registrar, then add a CNAME.

Comment: In my production server, there had exist `www`. Look at this : https://ibb.co/HdGK9mV

Comment: @SuccessMan Yes, do you have any further questions regarding this?

Comment: yes why does ssl state say "not secure"? I tried clicking "https only", but it didn't work

Comment: @SuccessMan If you want to use https, you need to add ssl binding, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings

Comment: How do I get the certificate?

Comment: @SuccessMan Here are some options for you to add certificates in App service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate